# STOCK Item details with last 4 recent vendors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get stock detail with last 4 most recent vendors on date, last price etc. Here is the SQL trying but not getting results.

```
SELECT S.Number, S.Description, S.BrandDescription, PL.ID, S.CatalogueDescription, S.InventoryUnitOfMeasure,  
                         S.TenderPrice, S.LastTenderedVendorId, S.Notes --, vendorNumber, VendorName, LastTransactionDate, po.OrderDate
FROM Stocks.Stock S LEFT OUTER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderLineItem PL on s.id = pl.StockId
                    inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrder po on po.Id = pl.PurchaseOrderId
                    left join 
                    (select vendorNumber, VendorName, POLID, LastTransactionDate from
                        (
                        SELECT top 4 v.Number vendorNumber, v.Name VendorName, PLL.Id POLID, max(por.TransactionDate) as LastTransactionDate,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY v.Number ORDER BY max(por.TransactionDate) DESC) AS rk
                        FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderLineItem PLL 
                        inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrder po on PLL.PurchaseOrderId = po.Id
                        inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderVendor POV on po.Id = POV.PurchaseOrderId
                        inner join Purchasing.Vendor V on pov.VendorId =  v.Id
                        left outer join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderReceipt POR on PLL.Id = por.PurchaseOrderLineItemId
                        group by v.Number, v.Name,PLL.Id
                        order by LastTransactionDate desc
                        ) A
                        where a.rk = 1) B on PL.Id = b.POLID
```

I need max of 4 last vendors so want 4 rows of each stock with vendor details. Will do group in report. LINQ query will also work.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: Stock-->PurchaseOrderLineItem-->PurchaseOrder-->PurchaseOrderVendor-->Vendor

Stock is main table, could have many vendors in past for same product. We need 4 recent 
last 4 distinct vendors with prices and last date purchased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your statement it is not clear which table is master and which is for details, but here is template for what you are trying to do. You can use outer apply:

```
Select * from master m
outer apply (select top 4 * From Details d where m.Id = d.Id order by someColumns desc)o
```

Comment: I think you need to apply **OUTER APPLY** instead of **LEFT JOIN** as Giorgi's code. @qazifarhan